# How to solve ".zshenv:4: command not found: " problem on terminal?

Tags: terminal

```
Last login: Wed Feb 21 13:30:47 on ttys002
**/Users/yeryeongseo/.zshenv:4: command not found:  **
yeryeongseo@seoyelyeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ % *cat .zshenv*
# HOMEBREW
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \ 
. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"
yeryeongseo@seoyelyeong-ui-MacBookPro ~ %
```

I fixed .zshenv code with GPT but it didn't help well.